# Running same source code for Baxter and Fetch arm movement?

Tags: ros, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible for running same source code for Baxter and Fetch arm movement? For Fetch actionlib stack is used for arm and gripper movement whereas in Baxter, actionlib stack is not used. Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256053/running-same-source-code-for-baxter-and-fetch-arm-movement?/) by [Waleed](https://answers.ros.org/users/29546/waleed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-04**:
Seeing as one uses actionlib and the other doesn't, I'd venture a guess and say: no, you won't be able to use the *same* source code, but perhaps with some changes it could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to run the same code on both Baxter and Fetch, likely you'll need to look at a different abstraction layer. I'd recommend using `MoveIt`'s `move_groups`. Theoretically (as I have not tried this myself) with minimal changes, you'll be able to abstract away the actual details of arm controllers and kinematics using `MoveIt` code.

Fetch `MoveIt` tutorial: http://docs.fetchrobotics.com/manipulation.html

Baxter `MoveIt` tutorial: http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/MoveIt_Tutorial

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2017-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0